# Trying to remove pesky alt text from lightbox gallery

Tags: javascript, html, image, lightbox

I have a gallery of my paintings at [www.unlicensedeyesurgery.com](http://www.unlicensedeyesurgery.com) which uses the famous Lightbox code. There is one problem with it: the Lightbox code uses the `rel` attribute of the anchor tag to display the description of the image in the pop-up "window." However, this somehow overrides the images' `alt` property and shows the ugly, HTML-code description in the mouse tooltip. Is there a way to disable to tooltip altogether—perhaps using JS?

Code Example:

```
<a href="#" rel="<em>lightbox html<span>styled</span> text in here<em>">
  <img src="photo.jpg" alt="this is overwritten" />
</a>
```

Comment: post actual code here because without it your question will be useless for comunity, after you fix your site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title overrided by `<a title="....">` as you have here image set it's title to alt content

you can do it with javascript:

```
window.onload=function() {
 var images=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
 for (var i in images) {
   images[i].title=images[i].alt ;delete(images[i].alt);
 }
};
```

Comment: Eicto, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! For the record (I'm just curious), is there a way to make the tooltip not appear at all?

Comment: I think in that case need to make lightbox to get image titles not from title but from other attribute, such as `data-title`, or make it to convert `title` to `data-title` at the initialisation moment,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the anchors rel is getting precedence over the images alt tag in the tooltip.

The solution is to add a title: `title="photo title"` to all your img tags and browsers will show that instead of the anchor's rel.