# How do I properly store description information for an image?

Tags: javascript, html

I have coded a custom lightbox for displaying images. Once an image is clicked and the lightbox opens, I would like a description for that image to appear. I am trying to store the description in the cleanest, most valid and proper way, yet I can't decide what I should do.

I have considered using custom data attributes, but I found this:

"Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements."

So data-picinfo or some other custom data field seems like it may not be appropriate? Or is it completely appropriate since my lightbox application will access the necessary data fields to display the proper information?

```
<img src="exampleimage.jpg" width="140" height="105" name="cool-image" data-picinfo="this was a beautiful day hiking the mountains"/>
```

What is the best and most proper way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: I would go ahead and use attribs if you'd like. Otherwise, use a JavaScript array or object.

Comment: Why not put the description in an element (say suitably styled span)? The client is primarily for display, there is no need to mess around with putting data in an attribute if all you are going to do with it is display it verbatum in a DOM element anyway. Do the work once at the server.

Comment: @RobG Okay but would I then have to display:none; the span until I wanted that info? I guess I would prefer a cleaner approach than that too.

Comment: @absentx i think all ideas are good, also i think this is not a big problem how to store the description you should focus more in finishing your site :D

Answer (score 1):

I would use the 'alt' attribute for image descriptions. Alt text not only ensures that the image tag abides by W3C standards for accessibility, but is also meant for exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Example:

```
<img src="exampleimage.jpg" width="140" height="105" name="cool-image" alt="this was a beautiful day hiking the mountains" />
```

At which point you can store that description for display later in a javascript variable like so:

```
var imgDescription = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute("alt");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The [alt attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/embedded-content-0.html#attr-img-alt) is intended for cases where the image is not displayed at all, i.e. it is an alternative to the image. That may or may not be the same as what the OP wishes to display.

Comment: @RobG but alt attribute is always here and is useful for the case when image is not displayed and also to extract its value using javascript, i think the idea is good

Comment: @medbo—it is redundant to display the image and the alt value. E.g. if the image is a pie chart, the alt value should descibe the segments and their proportions. That information should already be availble in the image itself (otherwise what's the point of the image?). The OP seems to what to provide a caption that provides more information, such as a brief analysis of the information in a pie chart. Of course I may be completely wrong about that, there's always a first time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what you need, i think there is no cleaner way to do this, and your lightbox need to get description from an other attribute, such as data-title

```
<img src="exampleimage.jpg" width="140" height="105" name="cool-image" data-title="this was a beautiful day hiking the mountains" />
```

how this help :)

Comment: True, but you might not want to see that tooltip on hover.

Comment: see also this discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794891/trying-to-remove-pesky-alt-text-from-lightbox-gallery

Comment: What should I be seeing in the link you provided?

Comment: @RobG if you look at edit history, you'll see that the answer originally had *title* and not *data-title*. :)

Comment: Then perhaps you should delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

On the technical side, the `title` attribute is closest to a “description”. But what really matters is what kind of information you have there, how you intend to use it, and whether it might be useful beyond your special use for it.

There is also the debated, little used `longdesc` attribute that is supposed to provide a link to a “long description”, but mainly for accessibility purposes (especially for people who do not see the image at all), and it is not included in HTML5 CR.

Comment: i think alt is a good way what is your opinion

Comment: @medBo, the question should be closed as basically an opinion poll, but my answer provides the technical answer on the basis of HTML specifications and practices. The `alt` attribute specifies by definition the content to be rendered (e.g. in speech or Braille) when the image is not rendered – not a description of the image. For example, for a purely decorative image, `alt=""` is adequate; a description would be something completely different.